# Uncaught exception no application instance

Tags: blackberry

i am working on UI-application that handles multiple entry point approach.

I am referring the [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Make-a-running-UI-application-go-to-the-background-and-resume-in/ta-p/445059) and try for make a demo.
Here is the code :-

```java
public class DemoApp extends UiApplication implements  RealtimeClockListener
{

    private static DemoApp dmMain ;
    private static final long dm_APP_ID =  0x6ef4b845de59ecf9L;

    private static DemoApp getDemoApp()
    {
        if(dmMain == null)
        {
            RuntimeStore dmAppStore = RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore();

            dmMain =  (DemoApp)dmAppStore.get(dm_APP_ID);
        }


        return dmMain;
    }

    private static void setDemoApp(DemoApp demoAppMain)
    {
        RuntimeStore dmAppStore = RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore();
        dmAppStore.remove(dm_APP_ID);
        dmAppStore.put(dm_APP_ID, demoAppMain);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Log.d(" Application argument  "+args);

        if( args.length > 0 && args[ 0 ].equals( "Demo_Alternate" ) )
        {
            Log.d("Running Demo_Alternate #### Running Demo_Alternate #### Running Demo_Alternate");

            dmMain = new DemoApp();
            dmMain.enterEventDispatcher();

            setDemoApp(dmMain);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Running Demo #### Running Demo #### Running Demo #### Running Demo");

            getDemoApp().initializeMain();
        }
    }

    public DemoApp() 
    {
        this.addRealtimeClockListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeMain() 
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    pushScreen(new DemoMainScreen());

                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });



    }

    public void clockUpdated() 
    {
        showMessage("DemoAppClock Updated");
        Log.d("DemoAppClock Updated #### DemoAppClock Updated #### DemoAppClock Updated");
    }


    private void showMessage(String message) 
    {
        synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) 
        {
            Dialog dlg = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, message, Dialog.OK, null, Manager.FIELD_HCENTER);
            Ui.getUiEngine().pushGlobalScreen(dlg, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
        }
    }

    }
```

:- I have created an alternate entry point named **Demo_Alternate** , that runs at start up.
   :- If the application has separate entry points, that means a separate process  the [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-do-multiple-entry-points-communicate/td-p/411393)

Now my questions are :-

1. While running the code, I am getting **"Uncaught exception : no application instance"**.
2. I just want to make **one application instance - don't want separate processes**.
3. Can we use (Application) **Singleton** approach for alternate entry-points?

Answer (score 1):

Only looked briefly at this code, but see an obvious problem here:

```
      dmMain.enterEventDispatcher();
      setDemoApp(dmMain);
```

enterEventDispatcher never returns, so you never put your Application instance in RuntimeStore.

I suggest you review the following KB article, you might find its approach to accessing a RuntimeStore maintained object easier to use.  Or not.

[Singleton using RuntimeStore](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-singleton-using-the-RuntimeStore/ta-p/442854)

**Update**

If this solution does not work, please update your original post with the corrected code.

Comment: ..I tried with  this approach dmMain = new DemoApp();
         setDemoApp(dmMain);
        dmMain.enterEventDispatcher();  ..getting the same exception ..that means we can't use these kind of approach.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly agree with Peter, that calling `setDemoApp(dmMain)` **after** `enterEventDispatcher()` means it doesn't get called.

That said, I think you have a more basic misunderstanding here.

**Using alternate entry points will create multiple processes.**  [See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529889/119114).

But, you say that you don't want separate processes.  Can you tell us *why not*?

Separate BlackBerry processes that are designed to work together can still share data, [using the RuntimeStore](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/running-in-the-background-part-2/), for example.

Maybe you could tell us more about what your "Demo" and "Demo Alternate" are supposed to do.

Comment: There is a use case for this where you only want one application instance, but also want it started when the device starts - which is what the BB KB article linked to in the question alludes too.  The alternate entry does not have to create an different application.  It can just add listeners for example.  Or just foreground an existing application that it knows about - which I think is what this poster is trying to do.

Comment: Maybe ... I'm not confident based on the question, and Mario's other questions, that this use case is really what he's after.  In any case, I think it's better for him to clarify what he's trying to do.  Nevertheless, the two entry points will cause two separate processes to call `main()`, right?  You could still have an `Application` singleton instance, for example, if he wanted only **one** application object, that would maintain some persistent state (not that this is the only way to achieve that).  I'm just trying to understand what he's trying to accomplish.